# html private-ip redirection for multi-server public website

Tags: html, networking, ip

(Sorry for poor English)

Hello, I'm going to build some website with two server (Google Cloud VM).
Apache web server has installed each VM.

Server 1 --
Public IP: known /
Private IP: 192.168.100.101

Server 2 --
Public IP: unknown / 
Private IP: 192.168.100.102

For redirection from ['index.html' in Server 1] to ['index.html' in Server 2], I coded in 'index.html' in Server 1: a href=192.168.100.102

I want to access from internet with Server 1's public IP, and click the link in 'index.html' in Server 1

expected result: view 'index.html' in Server 2

But its not work although Server 1&2 in same private network.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand properly about the href command you are using, since as you are stating that one instance is on Google Cloud VM and other is at Apache Web Server.
But, as per rules of Networking, you can't approach directly, you have to set virtual hosts inside the Apache Configuration Folder for second server index.html file's folder.

I can explain you properly but if you can apply more clarification to what you are asking! Plus, if you can apply this thing in Cisco Packet Tracer so that you can have some practical implementation idea.
I hope the answer is quite clear and your question needs more specific points to mention.